# configure subdomain for node.js

Tags: ubuntu, subdomain, node.js

I got ubuntu server with **express node.js** web site. I allready can request it:

- by ip: like that: `http://11.22.334.44`
- and by domain: like that: `http://my-domain.com`

I want to configure to request it by subdomain: like that: `http://my-subdomain.my-domain.com`. What should I do for this? Should I install dns? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just install nginx and [configure it as frontend server for node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015178/1024794). In nginx configure: everywhere instead of `domain.com` paste `subdomain.domain.com`. That's it.